# How can I make functions in a script "unavailable" when the script is imported?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have the following python "module" named `bloop.py`:

```
def f(x):
    return x+1

def a(x):
    return f(x)
```

How can I make function `f(x)` unavailable, or unusable, when the script is imported? This means that when the user attempts to do something like the below, it will fail.

```
import bloop
print bloop.f(10)
```

Comment: you can't . . . by convention, if you change the name from `f` to `_f`, that marks it as "private", but python doesn't enforce this.  the leading underscore is little more than convention.

Comment: You mean, you want bloop.a to succeed (which calls f) but bloop.f to produce some error? May I ask why?